# £ (Pound) Currency is not rendered by SKLabelNode in SpriteKit iOS 11.3.x

Tags: sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, sklabelnode

There is an In-app-Purchase screen where I have to display a button with text "unlock all £0.99" so that when player clicks that the In-app purchase moves forward.

The currency and localised price value are retrieved & populated from SKProduct.

Every other currencies which I have tested such as $, ¥, € renders fine the in label. However, when I use £ currency, the label just ignores that sign.

Is there are any workaround for it, other than reporting bug to apple at the moment?

No £ Sign rendered:

[image]

But shows in SKLabelNode.text:

[image]

Renders $ sign properly:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is the label and not the font that is the issue?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes indeed it was the font with issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cause of the issue. The issue was with the Font that I was using in game. It failed to render certain currencies such as £. When I tried using **Comic Sans MS** font, all currency signs include £ appeared magically. So I end up using **Comic Sans MS** font for that button text which shows currency sign.